# Counting emails from inbox folder in Outlook with Python (incorrect value)

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com, com-automation

I'm developing a Python script which will count the number of emails from my Inbox folder in Outlook, within a range of dates.

I'm using "Restrict" in order to set a limit for the emails I check. Variable "fecha" is static now just for tests.

The problem is that if I set the filter 11 days back, the count is correct (manually checked in my inbox), but if I set 12+ days back as a filter, the count is wrong (a lot more than it should). On the correct count, I get around 200 email average. On the wrong count, I get around 7000.

Does anyone know why is this and if there is any parameter I should change in order to get the correct data?

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders('account@domain.com').Folders('Inbox')
messages_inbox = inbox.Items
messages_inbox.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

fecha = now - datetime.timedelta(days = 13) #days=11, cuenta bien, days=12 cuenta mucho mas(de 2566 a 9479)
fecha = fecha.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0)
print(fecha)
rec_messages_pastmonth = messages_inbox.Restrict("([ReceivedTime] >= '" +fecha.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"')")

print(len(rec_messages_pastmonth)) 
print(fecha)
```

The output to this code is:

```
1141
2021-12-25 00:00:00.763213
```

Finally I found my error. It was because of the date format at the moment to send the date(fecha) to outlook. I was passing month-day-year, when outlook search was interpretating day-month-year. Fixed that, i finally get the correct value. Thanks to everyone for the effort.

Comment: Could you post your final search criteria string? How does it looks like?

Comment: I edited the question with the output. Regarding the search criteria string, i guess you are asking for the filter i use, and is this one(you can see it on the code: rec_messages_pastmonth = messages_inbox.Restrict("([ReceivedTime] >= '" +fecha.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"')")). Sorry if i misunderstood your question(I'm a newbie python student)

Comment: Finally I found my error. It was because of the date format at the moment to send the date(fecha) to outlook. I was passing month-day-year, when outlook search was interpretating day-month-year. Fixed that, i finally get the correct value.
Thanks to everyone for the effort.